# How to integrate bootstrap template into Angular please proper way with example

Tags: c#, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

i am new in angular.....
integrate the bootstrap template into a angular proj all asset file mean js and css file included in index.html these are not proper working also not responsive my site please tell me proper way then i have continue my proj Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Import your files to the `/assets` folder.

In `angular.json` under `"styles"` and `"scripts"`

```
"projects": {
    "projectname": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              // other css files go here
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              // other js files go here. 
            ]
```

Restart your application and it should work.

Comment: **not** put the .css or .js in assets folder. When you change the angular.json, Angular manange to create a full .css and a full.js. Assets folder are used to store necesaries  images or .json but **never** css and .js that you yet import using angular.json

Comment: Actually `angular.json` is used to import assets. And assets folder is used to store css and js. I think you need to read their official documentation of including a template

Comment: I want to say that if you use assets folder,  you has,e.g. bootstrap.min.css in the assets folder and in styles.688b7459da5be05405f0.css. (really your aplication never use the bootstrap.min.css in assets folder)

Comment: Your question and concern is not valid. Just because and asset is in an asset folder or any folder to that matter doesn't mean it cant be imported to `angular.json`

Comment: If our bootstrap.min.css is in a folder "css", you can use in angular.json, e.g. `"styles": ["src/styles.css","css/bootstrap.min.css"]`, take a look to this link:https://medium.com/@kmathy/angular-tips-and-tricks-for-css-structure-cb73fa50f0e8 (now, I didn't remember another more suiteble one)

Comment: Yes, you can. Could you please repeat your question again?

Comment: from the link: The “assets” folder is only for images and fonts for example. Don’t put your global styles there, or when you’ll build your application, they will be added inside, it is not necessary.

Comment: No, your build will come to one css file. If you have css inside assets folder it wont affect the build script. Anyways the build script fetches all assets from locations and jams it into a few files. So putting your css in assets folder will not affect your build script.

Comment: Yes, not affect your build script, the only effect are that you create an assets folder with **unnecesaries** files

Comment: Where else do you suggest to keep the asset files?? css and js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236086/discussion-between-ctrl-intelligence-and-eliseo).